# How to authenticate LDAP account?

Tags: perl

Couple of the Perl applications at my workplace require LDAP authentication. When those applications required the user to login, the application would anonymously connect to the LDAP server then searched for the user in the LDAP database. But now, we are no longer allowed to connect to the LDAP server anonymously, we are given a username and password to connect to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some code would be helpful, but, basically, if you have a username and password, you just need to bind to the LDAP directory.

The [Net::LDAP](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap/lib/Net/LDAP.pod) documentation has the following example:

```
$ldap = Net::LDAP->new( 'ldap.umich.edu' );
$mesg = $ldap->bind( 'cn=root,o=University of Michigan,c=us', password => 'secret' );
# your normal code goes here
```

Alternatively, of course, you could by-pass the username and password you were provided with and simply bind to the directory using the username and password supplied by the user.

Note that if you're binding against Active Directory, it's possible to bind using either 1) the user principal name of the account (e.g., user@umich.edu) or 2) the Kerberos ID (something like UMICH\user) in addition to using the DN of the provided user.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was actually over thinking my problem, and it was a stupid fix. We are getting rid of the LDAP server and getting a new one, so my problem was that I didn't know I could use the users credentials to authenticate the connection. But if I needed to search the LDAP server then I would need to do something else. Thanks though for your help.